# How to make a Tkinter loading screen that runs side-by-side the main program

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a small python app with Tkinter which involves collecting data in several lists, like this:

```
def main_process():
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    list3 = []
    
    #Data collection process

    #Resulting lists ready
```

The data collection process takes about 10 seconds, so I wanted to make a "Loading Screen" that works side-by-side the data collection process, without one following the other. For the status bar, I thought of introducing a variable **n** with value starting from 0, and increasing its value as and when each resultant lists get ready.

I attempted to create a function **loading_screen(n)** which will be called before the data processing, with **n** being the aforementioned variable containing a numeric value. And as the data_processing occurs, I shall run the **loading_screen** function to introduce the updated values of **n**, like so:

```
def main_process():
    
    def loading_screen(n):
        root = Tk()
        root.title('Stock Market App')
        root.geometry('800x300')
        
        status_label = Label(root, text = n)
        status_label.pack()

    loading_screen(0)
    
    # list1 Ready
    n += 10
    root.after(0, lambda: loading_screen(n))

    # list2 ready
    n += 10
    root.after(0, lambda: loading_screen(n))

    # And so on...
```

But it ended up showing me the loading screen after all the data processing has occurred. Can somebody please help me on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting function inside a function is not a good idea, better to create a `class`.

Then create two separate `Tk` windows.

Also, `after` is able to pass parameters so `lambda` is not necessary.

I've made a few small adjustments to conform to your question. The windows will now sit side by side.

Is this what you were looking for?

```py
import tkinter as tk

class main_process:

    def loading_screen( self, n ):
        self.status_label[ 'text' ] = '{}'.format( n )
        self.root.deiconify()
        self.status_label.focus()
        self.root.update()
        # insert processing here

    def __init__( self, x ):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.withdraw()

        self.root.title('Stock Market App')
        self.root.geometry( f'700x300+{x}+240')
        self.status_label = tk.Label( self.root, font = 'Helvetica 20 normal')
        self.status_label.pack()
        self.root.update()

screen_1 = main_process( 0 )
screen_1.root.after( 10, screen_1.loading_screen, 1 )

screen_2 = main_process( 705 )
screen_2.root.after( 10, screen_2.loading_screen, 2 )

screen_2.root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I am not much familiar with classes, but tell me this, are the two functions: loading_screen and __init__ working simultaneously and independent of each other? Because I intend to send some value from the processing function to the gui function

Comment: They are independent, that is you can destroy either one and the other will keep running but they are not running simultaneously. For that you would need to explore multi processing or threading.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can remove the gui like this

```
Labelone.destroy()
.
.
.
Loading_screen.place(...)
#you data collection code
Loading_screen.destroy()
Labelone.place(...)
.
.
.
```

So your data collection is going background and loading gui is place so user sees loading while python is collecting data